# Seven jobs processed on Seven machines. Each machine process only job and all jobs must be processed. How many assignments are possible?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, polynomials, inclusion-exclusion

[image]

Ignoring `Column #1`, `Column #7`, `Row #2`, `Row #7`, we can complete the rook polynomial for the smaller board (Since machine 1 has to process job 2, and machine 7 has to process job 7). This gives us the rook polynomial of

$R(x,B) =  1 + 4x + 6x^2 + 4x^3 + x^4$

If we let $A_i$ be that a machine is assigned to the shaded area, by principle of inclusion-exclusion we can arrive to the following:

$7! - (6!4 - 5!6 + 4!4 - 3!1)$

Would this be the right approach to the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the right basic approach, but you’ve not carried it out correctly. After you remove rows $2$ and $7$ and columns $1$ and $7$, you have this board, where I’ve numbered the forbidden squares:

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|} \hline
&&&&\;\;\\ \hline
&&&4&\\ \hline
&&3&&\\ \hline
&2&&&\\ \hline
1&&&&\\ \hline
\end{array}$$

The deleted rows and columns do not contribute anything, since the assigments there are fixed.

The rook polynomial for the *forbidden* sub-board is $(1+x)^4=1+4x+6x^2+4x^3+x^4$. If $A_k$ is the set of placements of $5$ rooks on this board that have a rook on cell $k$ (for $k=1,\ldots,4$), then an [inclusion-exclusion calculation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle#Statement) shows that the number of ‘bad’ job-machine assignments is

$$\begin{align*}
\left|\bigcup_{k=1}^4A_k\right|&=\sum_{\varnothing\ne I\subseteq[4]}(-1)^{|I|-1}\left|\bigcap_{k\in I}A_k\right|\\
&=\sum_{\varnothing\ne I\subseteq[4]}(-1)^{|I|-1}(5-|I|)!\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^4\binom4i(-1)^{i-1}(5-i)!\;.
\end{align*}$$

The number of acceptable assignments is therefore

$$\begin{align*}
5!-\sum_{i=1}^4\binom4i(-1)^{i-1}(5-i)!&=5!+\sum_{i=1}^4\binom4i(-1)^i(5-i)!\\
&=\sum_{i=0}^4\binom4i(-1)^i(5-i)!\\
&=5!-4\cdot4!+6\cdot3!-4\cdot2!+1\cdot1!\\
&=53\;.
\end{align*}$$

In the language of rook placements, we really are placing only $5$ rooks, not $7$, because $2$ of the original $7$ have forced placements and so contribute no variety.